# What Borg enhancements are retained by Jean-Luc Picard?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg, jean-luc-picard

What Borg enhancements does Captain Picard still possess from his time as Locutus?

It is clear that there is some link, which was especially seen in First Contact where Picard seemed to know where to hit the Borg cube.

Also, asides from the external Borg parts seen on Seven of Nine and the Borg children, would the internal enhancements still be the same as what Picard possesses?

Comment: "where Picard seemed to know where to hit the Borg cube" - that could simply be **knowledge**, not implants.

Comment: @DVK potentially yes; however, he seemed to be 'listening'/concentrating on something before making the call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Jean Luc Picard had been taken by the Borg and transformed into their spokes-borg Locutus. However after his recovery all the Borg implants and Borg nano-machines were removed.**

> Though his implants were removed and his wounds were allowed to heal, Picard's assimilation continued to haunt him. He returned to Earth, paying a visit to his family in La Barre, France, where he eventually came to terms with the ordeal. (TNG: "Family") **[Memory Alpha -> Locutus of Borg](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Locutus_of_Borg)**

In the second clash, it was not Borg implants which gave Picard an edge, but a memory of the Borg systems which allowed him to create an effective strategy against them.

> When the Borg attempted a second invasion in 2373, Picard's experience with the Borg not only gave him prior warning of the attack, but also allowed him to pinpoint a weakness in the Borg defenses, resulting in the fleet destroying the invading vessel. (Star Trek: First Contact)

The interaction between Jean Luc Picard and the Borg was a two-way transfer of information, the Borg gained valuable information about the Federation and its defense structure, ship capacities and ally information. What Jean Luc knew, the Borg knew. But the Borg share information fairly evenly so even Borg who have never met Locutus, know of him. This transfer of information also meant Jean Luc was privy to information about the Borg no human would know without direct experience (e.g. Seven of Nine).

Comment: in a way, this makes Capt. Picard that bit more awesome.

Comment: There must have been more to the connection than just a retained knowledge base. At multiple points during *First Contact* Picard hears the "song" of the Borg. The queen even comments on it. Also, Data is able to call out to Picard through the connection as everyone is boarding the escape pods.

Comment: Let's put it a different way. If there was anything physical left, Starfleet would have never allowed him to return to duty with even a single Borg nanoprobe active in his system. So whatever is left is perhaps a mildly telepathic connection or some kind of psychic entanglement because he was once part of the Collective.

Comment: @ Damien Did you just call Picard 'awesome'? eww...

Comment: @Jersey - sorry

Comment: I wonder if the borg made any improvements to Picard's artificial heart?  I wonder if he had to get another replacement post-borg?

Comment: Hate to be nit-picking, but that i.e. should be an e.g. -> http://theoatmeal.com/comics/ie